What will be the difference between the two types of "natural" miracles when Moshiach comes?
B"H
In the Maamar Kimei Tseischa, 5712, the Rebbe discusses different types of miracles.
First, there are miracles beyond nature, and miracles that are disguised in the 'garments' of nature.
And within that second type, there are two types.

Miracles disguised in nature in such a way that people seeing them happen can clearly see that there's a miracle, and the nature that the miracle is disguised in is only a disguise, but not that nature itself is the cause for what's happening; like the miracles of winning the Chanukah war, or Purim, where "the whole world" could see the miracle happening, and
Miracles that are so deeply disguised in nature, that no one knows that a miracle is there at all, not even the one to whom the miracle actually happened (like one is walking in the forest, and later discovered that a snake was about to bite him, but was killed before it could)

That's all fine so far. But then it says (in sif 2 and again in sif 8 with more detail), that the verse "like the days you went out of Egypt, I'll show you wonders", means that the second type of natural miracles, which are so deeply rooted in nature that even the one to whom they happen to doesn't know, will be seen.
Meaning we will be able to also so those miracles
Am I missing something? It seems like the entire distinction between the 2 types of natural miracles is that the first type are seen, and the second type aren't.
Now we're saying that in the future, we will also see the currently hidden miracles. In that case, what will be the difference between the two types?
Surely there will also be a difference between the supernatural miracles of the future (ingathering of the exiles, second splitting of the sea and river, resurrection of the dead etc) and the natural miracles that will also be shown in the future, so it stands to reason that, since some natural miracles are visible even now and some aren't, implying they are different types, these two types of natural miracles will still exist as unique entities.
Not only does it stand to reason that this is the case, but it's explicitly mentioned in sif 2 that this second category comes from a "higher source" than the first.
In addition, in note 25 in sif 3, it explicitly connects the idea that this second type is from a higher source to the advantage it has over even the first type of natural miracles (and especially supernatural miracles), that since one recognizes the miracle (in the first type), it's similar to the miracle "breaking" nature; but the second tyoe, which one doesn't realize at all, happens while nature is at it's full strength.
Technically the language it uses is "recognize if the garments of nature are only garments", instead of only relying on the terminology of "recognizing a miracle" or not, although both ideas are mentioned...
But if we will see the second type in the future, then how will it be different from the first type (which even then will clearly have a lesser shoresh as mentioned)?
I think the key is somehow in the terminology of "garments of nature", and understanding what exactly it will mean that we will see the second type, in such a way that it's different than seeing the first type, but I'm not sure exactly the explanation is

Not my area, but at first glance I would think the difference would be in human perception not in the manner with which it actually occurred. That in the future our apprehension of reality will more closely parallel reality as it is. So the miracle is still woven into nature in a way that normally precludes perception of it, but post-redemption we will merit to heightened perception and thus see (i.e. apprehend) that which is otherwise hidden.... just a thought

@Deuteronomy interesting hypothetical possibility
